# Setting up a local editor for swagger

Tags: swagger, documentation

I'm about to write some api docs using swagger but the web ui seems very broken for me. I'm trying to set it up so I can write in any editor on my local computer and have the result automatically reload in my browser (or at least automatically rebuilt so I can refresh to see the result). I can see there are a few tools [swagger codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#), [swagger ui](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui) but these seem to be fairly complex tools doing a lot of stuff I don't need and I can't work out how to set them up to do what I want. I can also see there is a plugin for VS Code that does this but I would rather use vim.

If I just want something that reads a text file and builds the html every time the text file gets changed how would I set that up?

Comment: By "web ui" do you mean http://editor.swagger.io? If so, how exactly does it seem "very broken" to you?

Comment: @Helen I had issues with the whole line being duplicated after my cursor after every letter input as well as text selection not working properly on firefox on linux.

Comment: Ouch, that's some nasty bug. Could you please open an issue in the Swagger Editor issue tracker at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues/new/choose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this [vscode plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Arjun.swagger-viewer) which gives a split screen view similar to the online editor but runs locally.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't want to go with Postman. Postman has many features including export and import the APIs. But if you don't want to use that or any other tool like swagger ui etc as you mentioned then you can build your own json file which you can use to build your html each time so that if you change anything in in json then it will reflect back in your web page.

Comment: Its not so much that I don't want to use swagger ui its just that I cant find a way to get it working how I want. Postman does not seem to have any offline way of developing documentation.

Comment: it has offline way. you can use localhost url in that like this. http://localhost/tour_travel/project/api/view-shuttle-buses-by-tto. But still if you don't want to use then there is only one way to to this and that is building your custom json and use those objects in your html file. If you want to go more advance and dynamic then you can run a node script at the backend.